# Python Thrift client immediately returning before result can be calculated

Tags: python, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have a Apache Thrift Client in Python which seemed to work fine for all calls except one.. when I perform this one API call .. instead of properly waiting for the result.. it just immediately returns with `None`  what gives? all other API calls have performed beautifully except this one

all calls after this call are hung.. is it a problem in the client? my server?

```
Testing my-thrift client...
ping! total client pool size = 1
my_status = ['MY_Status == pool->size() == 1, idle() == 1, busy() == 0']
MYRESULT = None

<after this it hangs>
```

```
print("Testing my-thrift client...")
my_client = MYThriftClient().connect_to_thrift_server(thrift_host="127.0.0.1")
print("ping! total client pool size = " + str(my_client.ping()))
print("my_status = " + str(my_client.status()))

objects_to_request = get_some_objects()

myresult = my_client.send_request_forstuff(objects_to_request, "SOMETYPE")

print("MYRESULT = " + str(myresult))
print("my_status = " + str(my_client.my_status()))
```

No exception occurs or is raised in the C++ Thrift Server..
Type is  `TThreadedServer` written in C++ if it matters.. but as I said other functions are holding just fine.. makes me think the client has a bug?

I've tried V0.13.0 and V0.15.0 and both have this behavior

```
class MYThriftClient:

    client_connection = None

    def connect_to_thrift_server(self, thrift_host, host_port=9090):

        if self.client_connection is None:

            transport = TSocket.TSocket(thrift_host, host_port)

            transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)

            protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)

            client = mythrift.Client(protocol)

            transport.open()

            self.client_connection = client

        return self.client_connection
```

The thrift definition file

```
// bunch of stuff, including the Definitions for the Objects, Exceptions

service mythrift {

    i32 ping() throws (1:CUSTOMException error),

    list<string> status() throws (1:CUSTOMException error),

    list<CustomResponse> request_forstuff(1:list<CUSTOMObject> request_objectss, 2:string some__type) throws (1:CUSTOMException error) 
}
```

Comment: omg i see it now, and it's super obvious but I am calling some `send____` function and there's no error or anything to warn you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was a silly error... I was calling a private function.. and because python is so permissive with all that.. it just let it proceed

so `my_client.send_request_forstuff`

should instead have been

`my_client.request_forstuff`